# How to make a ruby thread execute a function of my choosing?

Tags: ruby, database, multithreading, sinatra

Is it possible to create a "worker thread" so to speak that is on standby until it receives a function to execute asynchronously?

Is there a way to send a function like

```
def some_function
 puts "hi"
 # write something
 db.exec()
end
```

to an existing thread that's just sitting there waiting?

The idea is I'd like to pawn off some database writes to a thread which runs asynchronously.

I thought about creating a [Queue](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) instance, then have a thread do something like this:

```
$command = Queue.new
Thread.new do
 while trigger = $command.pop
  some_method
 end
end

$command.push("go!")
```

However this does not seem like a particularly good way to go about it. What is a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The [thread gem](https://github.com/meh/ruby-thread) looks like it would suit your needs:

```
require 'thread/channel'

def some_method
  puts "hi"
end

channel = Thread.channel

Thread.new do
  while data = channel.receive
    some_method
  end
end

channel.send("go!")
channel.send("ruby!") # Any truthy message will do
channel.send(nil)     # Non-truthy message to terminate other thread

sleep(1)              # Give other thread time to do I/O
```

The channel uses [ConditionVariable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/ConditionVariable.html), which you could use yourself if you prefer.